# Can't import component to another component through using selector

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Angular 12 - This is my angular version

I tried to import a component to another component using a selector.I got this following error.

1. If 'app-features' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-features' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/in86w.png)

Comment: Hello @Nimeshika, Can you please provide the source code to find where the issue is occurred?

Answer (score 0):

does `app-features` have it's own module where the component is declared and exported? if yes, you should import the module in the same module as home-component.

If not, you should declare the `app-features` component in the same module as home-component or in AppModule

Answer (score 0):

this error happens when angular can not find which module a component actually belongs to!
so first just find app-features module
then add it to imports array of its module! easy!